# Codeigniter. get values from database in 3 table(many to many)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, left-join

sorry for my english:)

i am the newbie in Codeigniter, and start my learn with writing simple Blog
i have 3 tables

```
Table 1 'news'
---------------------------------
id | title | slug | text | image |
---------------------------------
Table 2 'categories'
----------
id | name |
----------
Table 3 'news_cat'
---------------------------
id | news_id | category_id |
---------------------------
in this table `id` is autoincrement
```

i want see what the categories have one post from 'news' in my view page

View file

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

   <?php echo $news_item['title'] ?>

   <p><?=$news_item['text'] ?>
<? foreach($news_item['cat_data'] as $cat_data):?>
The category is:<?=$cat_data ?>

<?php endforeach;?>

<?php if(!empty($news_item['image'])) { ?>
<img  src ="/uploads/<?=$news_item['image'];?>">
<?php } ?>

<a href="news/<?=$news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a>

Controller

public function index()
{

$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();

foreach ($data['news'] as $key => $value) :
    $id = $data['news'][$key]['id'];
 $data['news'][$key]['cat_data'] = $this->categories_model->get_by_id($id);
    // IN THIS I HAVE QUESTION, how insert in my array several values by method           get_by_id() and what must have this method

$data['title'] = 'News archive';
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('news/index', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

Model
    public function get_by_id($id)
    {

```
  in this model i think i need use JOIN, but how i don`t know

}
```

Comment: in this table, id is redundant

Answer (score 0):

hope the below code sample may help you .. if i understood your question, this will get you the list of category name and id value

```
$this->db->select('categories.name,categories.id');
$this->db->from('categories');
$this->db->join('news_cat',"news_cat.category_id= categories.id");
$query = $this->db->get();
$data['category_list']=$query->result_array();
```